# Can i generate the input given the output in a pretrained Tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, output, reverse-engineering

Let's assume i have trained a model for the MNist task, given the following code:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 15
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 256 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 256 # 2nd layer number of features
n_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
# Test model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
# Calculate accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        avg_acc = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            batch_acc = accuracy.eval({x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
            avg_acc += batch_acc / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            test_acc = accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})
            print(
                "Epoch:",
                '%04d' % (epoch+1),
                "cost=",
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost),
                "average_train_accuracy=",
                "{:.6f}".format(avg_acc),
                "test_accuracy=",
                "{:.6f}".format(test_acc)
            )
    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

So this model predicts the number shown in an image given the image.
Once i have trained it, could i make the input a 'variable' instead of 'placeholder' and try to reverse engineer the input given an output ?
For example i would like to feed the output '8' and produce a representative image of number eight.

I thought of:

1. Freezing the model
2. Add a variable matrix 'M' of the same size as the input between the input and the weights
3. Feed an Identical matrix as input to the input placeholder
4. Run the optimizer to learn the 'M' matrix.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to reverse the model in the sense that the input should be a digit and the output an image displaying that digit (in say, handwritten form), it is not quite possible to do with machine learning models.

Because machine learning models attempt to create generalizations from the input (so that similar input will provide similar output, although the model was never trained on it) they tend to be quite lossy. Additionally, the reduction from hundreds, thousands and more input variables into a single output variable obviously has to lose some information in the process.

More specifically, although a [Multilayer Perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron) (as you're using in your example) is a fully connected Neural Network, some weights are expected to be zero, thus completely dropping the information in certain input variables. Moverover, the same output of a neuron can be retrieved by multiple distinctive input values to it's function, due to the many degrees of freedom.

It is theoretically possible to replace those degrees of freedom and lost information with specifically crafted or random data, but that does not guarantee a successful output.

On a side note, I'm a bit puzzled by this question. If you are able to generate that model yourself, you could also create a similar model that does the opposite. You could train a model to accept an input digit (and perhaps some random seed) and output an image.